# Nginx not starting after restarting VPS

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, vps

[image]

I am getting these error after restaring my vps and restarting nginx. Can someone tell me whats the problem?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/inforgein.conf` references a file `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` that doesn't exist or isn't readable.

Comment: ok, i got it fixed. As you said, there was an error in inforgein.conf. Fixed it now. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys. I got it corrected myself. There was an error in inforgein.conf. I restored the old configuration file.